# Enable and Disable two different Buttons based on Check boxes selected - JQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a table, but I need to add some functionality so that if you select just one option the individual action menu should be active and the top action menu should be greyed out. Currently, if you select one option it disables the table action menu and enables the top action menu. Is there a way that I can get it to work so that if just one record is selected the top menu is disabled.

How it works currently:

Select All - table buttons are disabled and top button is enabled. If you de-select the Select All then that button is disabled

If you select 2 or more from the table then the table buttons are disabled and the top menu is enabled.

**JQuery**

```
// Checks individual checkboxes and displays the count
    $(".individual").on("change", determineActionButtonAvailability);

    $(".selectall").click(function () {
        $(".individual").prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
        determineActionButtonAvailability();
    });

    //Disable Top Verify Button if two or more checkboxes are selected.
    $('.verify-btn').prop('disabled', true);
    $(".individual").on("click", function () {
        if ($(".individual:checked").length > 1) {
            $('.verify-btn').prop('disabled', false);
        }
        else {
            $('.verify-btn').prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });

    //Disable Action Button in the columns when more than one checkbox is selected
    $('.table-btn').prop('disabled', false);
    $(".individual").on("click", function () {
        if ($(".individual:checked").length > 1) {
            $('.table-btn').prop('disabled', false);
            $(".verify-btn").prop('disabled', true);
        }
        else {
            $('.table-btn').prop('disabled', false);
            $(".verify-btn").prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });

    // When one or more works are selected, will enable the top action menu.
    // Will disable when none selected.
    function determineActionButtonAvailability()
    {
        if ($(".individual:checked").length > 0)
        {
            $(".records-selected").show();
            $("#selected").text($(".individual:checked").length);
            $("#total").text($(".individual").length);

            $(".verify-btn").prop('disabled', false);
            $('.table-btn').prop('disabled', true);
        }
        else {
            $(".records-selected").hide();

            $(".verify-btn").prop('disabled', true);
            $('.table-btn').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    }
```

**Table**

```
 <table class="table table-striped table-hover dataTable admin-form theme-primary newsongsTable" width="100" role="grid">
    <thead id="tableHeader">
    <tr>
        <th class="bg-white">Select</th>

        <th class="sorting text-left hidden-xs hidden-sm @Html.SortTitleItem("UniqueCode", Model.PagingInfo.SortPropertyName, Model.PagingInfo.SortAscending)">
            <a href="@Url.Action("NewSongs", "SongsManagement", new
                     {
                         workcode = workCode,
                         page = 1,
                         take = Model.PagingInfo.Take,
                         sortBy = "UniqueCode",
                         sortAsc = Model.PagingInfo.SortPropertyName != "UniqueCode" || !Model.PagingInfo.SortAscending
                     })" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Sort by Date">Song ID</a>
        </th>

        <th class="sorting text-left @Html.SortTitleItem("Title", Model.PagingInfo.SortPropertyName, Model.PagingInfo.SortAscending)">
            <a href="@Url.Action("NewSongs", "SongsManagement", new
                     {
                         workcode = workCode,
                         page = 1,
                         take = Model.PagingInfo.Take,
                         sortBy = "Title",
                         sortAsc = Model.PagingInfo.SortPropertyName != "Title" || !Model.PagingInfo.SortAscending
                     })" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Sort by Song Title">Song Title</a>
        </th>
        <th class="sorting text-left hidden-xs hidden-sm @Html.SortTitleItem("CreatedDate", Model.PagingInfo.SortPropertyName, Model.PagingInfo.SortAscending)">
            <a href="@Url.Action("NewSongs", "SongsManagement", new
                     {
                         workcode = workCode,
                         page = 1,
                         take = Model.PagingInfo.Take,
                         sortBy = "CreatedDate",
                         sortAsc = Model.PagingInfo.SortPropertyName != "CreatedDate" || !Model.PagingInfo.SortAscending
                     })" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Sort by Created Date">Created Date</a>
        </th>
        <th class="sorting text-left hidden-xs @Html.SortTitleItem("ArtistAccount.AccountName", Model.PagingInfo.SortPropertyName, Model.PagingInfo.SortAscending)">
            <a href="@Url.Action("NewSongs", "SongsManagement", new
                     {
                         workcode = workCode,
                         page = 1,
                         take = Model.PagingInfo.Take,
                         sortBy = "ArtistAccount.AccountName",
                         sortAsc = Model.PagingInfo.SortPropertyName != "ArtistAccount.AccountName" || !Model.PagingInfo.SortAscending
                     })" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Sort by Account Name">Account Name</a>
        </th>
        <th class="sorting text-left hidden-xs hidden-sm @Html.SortTitleItem("Catalogue.Name", Model.PagingInfo.SortPropertyName, Model.PagingInfo.SortAscending)">
            <a href="@Url.Action("NewSongs", "SongsManagement", new
                     {
                         workcode = workCode,
                         page = 1,
                         take = Model.PagingInfo.Take,
                         sortBy = "Catalogue.Name",
                         sortAsc = Model.PagingInfo.SortPropertyName != "Catalogue.Name" || !Model.PagingInfo.SortAscending
                     })" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Sort by Catalogue Name">Catalogue Name</a>
        </th>
        <th class="bg-white th-10 text-center">Action</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var t in Model.Songs)
    {
        <tr data-id="@t.ID"
            data-isdeleted="@t.IsDeleted"
            data-rowversion="@t.RowVersion"
            data-uniqueworkid="@t.WorkUniqueCode"
            data-songtitle="@t.SongTitle"
            data-created-date="@t.CreatedDate"
            date-accountname="@t.AccountName"
            data-cataloguename="@t.CatalogueName">

            <td><label><input type="checkbox" class="individual" data-checkbox="checkbox"/></label></td>
            <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">@t.WorkUniqueCode</td>
            <td>@t.SongTitle</td>
            <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">@t.CreatedDate</td>
            <td class="hidden-xs">@t.AccountName</td>
            <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">@t.CatalogueName</td>
            <td class="updateTableRow text-center">
                <div class="dropdownContainer btn-group text-right">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary br2 btn-xs fs12 dropdown-toggle table-btn" id="table-actionbtn" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        Action
                        <span class="caret ml5"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Verify Song" data-rowhover="activateTableRow">Verify Song</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Reject Song" data-rowhover="deleteTableRow">Reject Song</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        //tableRowIndex++;
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If anyone is able to give me some advice as it has me stumpted.

Comment: There's a bunch of extra mark-up there. Can you boil it down to what is pertinent to the question, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have managed to get it working, after much head-scratching, I changed the count to 1 this solved the issue. Full tested it now performs as intended.

```
    // Checks individual checkboxes and displays the count
    $(".individual").on("change", determineActionButtonAvailability);

    $(".selectall").click(function () {
        $(".individual").prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
        determineActionButtonAvailability();
    });

    //Disable Top Verify Button if two or more checkboxes are selected.
    $('.verify-btn').prop('disabled', true);
    $(".individual").on("click", function () {
        if ($(".individual:checked").length > 1) {
            $('.verify-btn').prop('disabled', false);
        }
        else {
            $('.verify-btn').prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });

    //Disable Action Button in the columns when more than one checkbox is selected
    $('.table-btn').prop('disabled', false);
    $(".individual").on("click", function () {
        if ($(".individual:checked").length > 1) {
            $('.table-btn').prop('disabled', true);
        }
        else {
            $('.table-btn').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });

    // When one or more works are selected, will enable the top action menu.
    // Will disable when none selected.
    function determineActionButtonAvailability() {
        if ($(".individual:checked").length > 1) {
            $(".records-selected").show();
            $("#selected").text($(".individual:checked").length);
            $("#total").text($(".individual").length);

            $(".verify-btn").prop('disabled', false);
            $(".table-btn").prop('disabled', true);
        }
        else {
            $(".records-selected").hide();

            $(".verify-btn").prop('disabled', true);
            $(".table-btn").prop('disabled', false);
        }
    }
```